# Unable to detect faces in image from camera

Tags: android

I am unable to take a picture with the camera and have it detect any faces. I display the picture on the screen and can clearly see my face on the image, but it is never detected. My logcat prints "No face found!"

```
public void takePictureNoPreview(Context context) {
    camera = openFrontFacingCamera();
    if (camera != null) {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture dummy = new SurfaceTexture(0);
            camera.setPreviewTexture(dummy);
            camera.startPreview();

            camera.takePicture(null, null, this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

    } else {
        // booo, failed!
    }
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Picture taken");
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
    FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), 1);
    Face[] faces = new Face[1];
    int foundFaces = faceDetector.findFaces(bitmap, faces);
    if (foundFaces > 0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Found a face!");
    } else {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "No face found!");
    }
    camera.release();
    sendImageToActivity(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Do you get the "No face found!" message? Or is something else not working?

Comment: It prints "No Face found!"

Comment: Can you post a sample photo?

Comment: I can work on that, but I assure you my face looks like a face. I've also tried printed pictures and other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to rotate my camera image by 90 degrees. The image being returned from the camera was off by 90 degrees and that kept the FaceDetector from properly processing the image.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```